# PHP - Join statement duplicates records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, inner-join

I have quite a large query, which basically shows the different forums I have stored in my database, to my users:

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT 
        c.forum_id as category_id,
        c.forum_name as category_name,
        t.forum_id as id,
        t.forum_name as name,
        t.forum_desc as description,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_topics WHERE forum_id=t.forum_id AND topic_deleted=0) as topics_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE forum_id=t.forum_id AND post_deleted=0) as posts_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id=lp.topic_id AND post_deleted=0) as last_post_count,
        lp.topic_id as last_post_topic_id,
        lp.topic_title as last_post_topic_title,
        lp.post_time as last_post_time,
        lp.username as last_post_username
    FROM forum_cats as t
    JOIN forum_cats as c on c.forum_id = t.forum_type_id
    left join (
        SELECT 
            ft.topic_id,
            ft.title as topic_title,
            tmp.post_time,
            u.username,
            fp.forum_id
        FROM
            forum_posts fp
            join forum_topics ft on ft.topic_id = fp.topic_id
            join users u on u.id = fp.userid
            join (
                select forum_id, max(`post_time`) `post_time`
                from forum_posts fp
                where fp.post_deleted = 0
                group by forum_id
                ) as tmp on (fp.forum_id = tmp.forum_id and fp.post_time = tmp.post_time)
        where post_deleted = 0 and ft.topic_deleted = 0
    ) as lp on lp.forum_id = t.forum_id
    where t.forum_active = 1 and c.forum_active = 1
    order by category_id, t.forum_id
");

    $stmt->execute();
```

I then do a while loop to show all the records:

```
while (($row = $stmt->fetch())) {
echo $row['name']; 
}
```

The problem is, that during the while loop, I get fine results **sometimes**!

It should look like this:

```
forum1
forum2
forum3
forum4
forum5
forum6
```

etc.

But sometimes I get results like this:

```
forum1
forum1
forum1
forum1
forum2
forum3
forum4
forum5
forum6
```

Some of the rows (it's quite random which row) are being 'duplicated'.

Can someone help me shed light on this?

Comment: Presumably, the query `SELECT t.forum_id FROM forum_topics t` generates the same error?

Comment: @Strawberry would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Just a wild guess but... I would say that your third join (the subquery) which is bringing posts on the main query makes the duplicates as you may have many posts for one forum. Can you run the subquery alone (you name it ```lp```) and check if there are repeated ```forum_id``` fields?

Comment: Just trying to establish whether the problem is in PHP or MySQL

Comment: This join seems odd: `FROM forum_cats as t JOIN forum_cats as c on c.forum_id = t.forum_type_id`. What are `forum_cats` (categories?),  and why do you need to join that table on itself by forum_id and type_id? It looks like an error, and even if it isn't, it might return duplicates.

Comment: @GolezTrol forum_cats are categories. I have all my forums listed in forum_cats

Comment: Ok. Question remains: Why do you join that table by itself on that type id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping by adding `GROUP BY t.forum_id`:

```
SELECT 
    c.forum_id as category_id,
    c.forum_name as category_name,
    t.forum_id as id,
    t.forum_name as name,
    t.forum_desc as description,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_topics WHERE forum_id=t.forum_id AND topic_deleted=0) as topics_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE forum_id=t.forum_id AND post_deleted=0) as posts_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id=lp.topic_id AND post_deleted=0) as last_post_count,
    lp.topic_id as last_post_topic_id,
    lp.topic_title as last_post_topic_title,
    lp.post_time as last_post_time,
    lp.username as last_post_username
FROM forum_cats as t
JOIN forum_cats as c on c.forum_id = t.forum_type_id
left join (
    SELECT 
        ft.topic_id,
        ft.title as topic_title,
        tmp.post_time,
        u.username,
        fp.forum_id
    FROM
        forum_posts fp
        join forum_topics ft on ft.topic_id = fp.topic_id
        join users u on u.id = fp.userid
        join (
            select forum_id, max(`post_time`) `post_time`
            from forum_posts fp
            where fp.post_deleted = 0
            group by forum_id
            ) as tmp on (fp.forum_id = tmp.forum_id and fp.post_time = tmp.post_time)
    where post_deleted = 0 and ft.topic_deleted = 0
) as lp on lp.forum_id = t.forum_id
where t.forum_active = 1 and c.forum_active = 1
GROUP BY t.forum_id
order by category_id, t.forum_id
```

Comment: Or change the first `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT`. After all, why would you group if there is nothing to aggregate? Either way, this will remove the symptoms, but in many cases unexpected duplicate rows indicate an error that needs to be solved. Now you're just suppressing the symptom.

Comment: If you do add `GROUP BY`, it should go before `ORDER BY`.